# Django Haystack Elasticsearch returning everything on development server but works in shell

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

After installing elasticsearch server in my local machine and running development server, I have found out that any query returns every index. However, when I check in shell to make sure everything is indexed correctly, it is working flawlessly. The problem still exists when I force `haystack.views.SearchView` to return queried results:

```
class SearchView(object):
    template = 'search/search.html'
    extra_context = {}
    query = ''
    results = EmptySearchQuerySet()
    request = None
    form = None
    results_per_page = RESULTS_PER_PAGE

    def get_results(self):
        return SearchQuerySet().auto_query('john')
```

returns every indexed data to the template.

On the other hand:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> SearchQuerySet().all()
[<SearchResult: custom_user.user (pk=u'1')>, <SearchResult: custom_user.user (pk=u'2')>, <SearchResult: custom_user.user (pk=u'3')>, u'...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>> SearchQuerySet().auto_query('john')
[<SearchResult: custom_user.user (pk=u'1')>]
```

I am using GAE dev_appserver.py if that has to matter at all. Below is other files that I use.

myapp/settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

custom_user/search_indexes.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from haystack import indexes

from .models import User


class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='username')
    nickname = indexes.CharField(model_attr='nickname')

    def get_model(self):
        return User

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('nickname')
```

Comment: Have you tried just inheriting from Haystack's SearchView? E.g., `class MySearchView(haystack.views.SearchView)`

Comment: I tried customising 'def basic_search()'.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be an issue with how you're setting up your view and inheriting from haystack. Can you try the following verbatim:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
class MySearchView(SearchView):

    def get_results(self):
        return SearchQuerySet().auto_query('john')
```

Comment: Just did and got the same result of getting every indexed data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue and I've looked around trying to understand why it's happening. The closest thing to a solution that I've found was: http://tech.marksblogg.com/query-elasticsearch-from-google-app-engine-gae.html